# How to remove internet usability traces in Ubuntu?

Tags: internet

I've rented a laptop from my college and need to give it back soon. I haven't done anything illegal or bad with that computer, but still I want to give it back as cleanly as possible. I mostly want to delete all local internet usability traces. Since I'm new to Ubuntu, I'm not sure if there are some logfiles in the background somewhere (for example logging all url's visited and so on...). You Linux veterans, what files to delete and where to find them? Thanks!

Comment: Open your browser. Settings --> History.  Delete All.

Comment: @user535733 haha, besides that :)

Comment: Are you asking if Ubuntu tracks your internet browsing history? No. Your browser does. Your ISP does. Certain state actors do. Certain malicious actors do. Certain commercial actors do. But a default install of Ubuntu (except the browser) does not. We cannot speak to any additional spyware that the hardware's owner or any of those actors may have installed.

Comment: if you have the ability to you could also try deleting the browser profile. For example a list of profiles are found at `~/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini` From this you should be able to remove the folder that corresponds with the profile in question. NOTE: anyone who really wanted to can recover photos that were viewed in the web browser through programs like photorec. Without wiping the partition that /home is on, this is *almost* unavoidable in hindsight

Comment: @user535733 Thanks. The info about ubuntu is most important to me.

Comment: @stratus Thanks. I will keep the hidden folder in mind :)